# Laravel - Why my code isnt displaying all the collapses ?

Tags: laravel

This code need to display all "subcategory"  for each "subcategories"
But the view result is the first subcategory only. 
Where i missed please ?

View 1 :

```
@foreach($treeView as $category)
 <div  class="collapse multi-collapse collapse in " id="8"  >         
   <div class="col-md-2"> {{ $category->account_name}}</div>
      <div class=" float-right"><button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ $category->id}}8" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="{{ $category->id}}8" @click="getSubaccount(); getNumberrawaccount();">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button></div>

  <br>                     
<div class="list-group">
@if(count($category->subcategories))
@include('tree2',['subcategories'=>$category->subcategories])
@endif
   </div>
@endforeach
```

View 2 : tree2

```
<div class='list-group'>
     <br>
      @foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
    <div class="list-group col-md-12">
     <div  class="collapse multi-collapse" id="{{ $category->id}}8" >
             <div class="col-md-4"> {{ $subcategory->subaccount_name }}</div>
             <div class=" float-right"><button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ $subcategory->id}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button></div>
    </div>
        </div>
  @endforeach
  </div>
```

Thank you

Comment: this return with `array` `$category->subcategories`??

Comment: Yes, but shows only the first result, not all of them. 
When i use collapse in in my class, it does.